# weird SIGSEGV crash in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, crash

About 10+ crash reported by crittercism.

Name: SIGSEGV
Reason: SEGV_MAPERR

Seems it is a UIScrollView/UITableView animating or scrolling issue.
How can I find the root cause?

Stack:

```
0   
libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000195fafbd0 objc_msgSend + 12
1   
UIKit 0x00000001892b1db8 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _delegateScrollViewAnimationEnded] + 64
2   
UIKit 0x00000001892b1d30 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _scrollViewAnimationEnded:finished:] + 204
3   
UIKit 0x0000000189366814 -[UIAnimator stopAnimation:] + 500
4   
UIKit 0x0000000189366248 -[UIAnimator(Static) _advanceAnimationsOfType:withTimestamp:] + 332
5   
QuartzCore 0x0000000188b4629c CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 28
6   
QuartzCore 0x0000000188b46134 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items() + 320
7   
IOKit 0x0000000185921470 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
8   
CoreFoundation 0x0000000184712dc4 __CFMachPortPerform + 176
9   
CoreFoundation 0x0000000184727a54 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
10  
CoreFoundation 0x00000001847279b4 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 432
11  
CoreFoundation 0x0000000184725934 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
12  
CoreFoundation 0x00000001846512d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
13  
GraphicsServices 0x000000018de676fc GSEventRunModal + 164
14  
UIKit 0x0000000189216fac UIApplicationMain + 1484
15  
MyApp 0x000000010001d280 main (main.m:14)
16  
libdyld.dylib 0x000000019661aa08 start + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when a controller and/or its table is deallocated during an animation.  The OS still triggers delegate methods (e.g., `-scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` or `-scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`) when it finishes with the animation, but because the objects no longer exist things get weird.

The best fix is to nil the delegate in the controller's `dealloc` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If so, how can I locate the table. There're a lot of tables in the app....
And I think there might be some wrong code result in this problem.
Not all the tables.
Or you mean that this is a bug/defect from apple?

Comment: You should clear the delegate for all tables.  It's impossible for me to tell you which table it is, but you could add Crittercism breadcrumbs to help you narrow down where the user was when the crash occurred.